# Propagate systemd reloads with sd_notify()

Tags: linux, daemon, systemd

I'm implementing a daemon that supports [sd_notify()](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html), this daemon generates configuration files for other daemons.

I'd like to make use of systemd dependency management to propagate reloads to other daemons, so if my daemon generates new configuration, dependant daemons reload. For that I was trying to use `RELOADING=1` systemd notification and `PropagatesReloadTo=`/`ReloadPropagatedFrom=` properties to notify dependant services, but it seems that this property only propagates reloads originated by `systemctl reload` and not the ones notified with `sd_notify()`.

Is there any way of using `sd_notify()` or something similar to notify dependant services that they should reload?

Comment: Discussing about this in https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/6550

Comment: `RELOADING=1`  should be working now as this is merged https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/6550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was indeed not working because it was not supported, but after the merge of [#6550](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/6550), using `sd_notify()` from a service to notify `RELOADING=1` notifies also units in the list of `PropagatesReloadTo=`/`ReloadPropagatedFrom=`.